# ingest JSON-STAT from RESTapi to csv on Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to make a request to an RESTapi of the Norwegian statistics bureau.
According to their api I need to make a POST request (thats not usual but that is ok) to get the tables that I need. In the body of the POST request I can specify with kind of table I want.

What I get is a JSON-STAT file. I need some help about how to handle it on Azure Data Factory. I read on documentation that ADF supports just JSON when using REST API. Does it mean that it also supports JSON-STAT ? If so How can I handle it on the activity ( source/sink ).

Thanks in advance,
Nunotrt

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of how the JSON-STAT file looks like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! please check the attached file: [link] (https://home.mycloud.com/action/share/6ff12bf6-0463-4045-bed5-ebe0691c7a43)

Comment: to get this response we need to send a post request to Norwegian statistic bureau ... you can test it using their console: [link] (https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/en/console) with the following url [link] (https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/en/table/01222/) and query -> "{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Region",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "agg:KommSummer",
        "values": [
          "K-3006"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "json-stat2"
  }
}"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample process of JSON-STAT file ingest from REST API . Create a new REST dataset.  [image]  Create Linked services to the REST API.  [image]  Provide REST dataset as the source for the copy activity and also with the POST request method, providing the request body(`{ "query": [ { "code": "Region", "selection": { "filter": "agg:KommSummer", "values": [ "K-3006" ] } } ], "response": { "format": "json-stat2" } }`)

[image]  Create a linked services for sink dataset.  [image]  Create a file path for the sink dataset to get the file into the location.  [image]  [image]  [image]  Result we get as per the expectations.  [image]

Comment: Wow, great! thanks for the help. I ll try again so hopefully I manage to do it :)

Comment: Hei again. It is true it works , but when I want to change file type from json-stat to parquet or csv ... It seems data factory cant handle it. I have another json files on the pipeline that copies to parquet and it works great. When I try with this json-stat files it seems it does not work,,,, any work around regarding this challenge/issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a json-stat file to csv or parquet, it is an alternative to you use a python code as a part of your Data Factory job.

The python library [pyjstat](https://pypi.org/project/pyjstat/) makes it easy to convert json-stat to a DataFrame, and from DataFrame to any other file format.

Here are an example with json-stat 1.2

```
import pandas as pd
from pyjstat import pyjstat as pyj

# url
file_ssb = 'https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/1102.json'

# Upload data to memory
dataset = pyj.Dataset.read(file_ssb)

# Write json-stat to dataframe
df = dataset.write('dataframe')
print(df)

# Save as csv
df.to_csv('../Data/test_jsonstat.csv')
```

Comment: thats true ! thanks for that, I was trying to do exactly what this code do on data flow ADF! thanks anyway for your support